# Using a GET request to persist items in database

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, microservices

I currently have a scenario with two java microservices, lets say **StudentService** and **UserService**. Both services persist data in respective nosql databases.

The client makes a ***GET api/v1/students/{id}*** to retrieve a particular student from the **StudentService**. In some cases, some entries for students in the Student table do not contain a field *age*. I currently retrieve age for this student from the **UserService** and return it to my client.

Although this seems quite straightforward and seems to work, I am not really a big fan of this solution because we could end up with a nested request for each GET request from the client(worst case).

The alternative I am thinking of is, when the StudentService cannot find age for a student, it retrieves age from UserTable and also adds this field in my *UserTable*. By doing this, next time the client calls ***GET api/v1/students/{id}*** for the same user, the UserService has everything it needs and I do not have to go to UserService again.

On the contrary, modifying contents of a Table with a GET request is not ideal.

Making major modifications to the structure of my Tables and services is unfortunately not possible because of legacy reasons.

How would you guys suggest I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and cache the data you need in your table.

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe.  What
> it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and
> therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface
> or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that
> causes loss of property (money, BTW, is considered property for the
> sake of this definition). -- Fielding, 2002

[Safe](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-9.2.1), here, means "essentially read-only".  It means that general purpose components (like a web crawler) can submit the request on their own, without needing to worry about underlying cost.  It means that a user agent can "pre-fetch" the resource before the user decides to click on the link.

Your server's making changes to its underlying data store is an *implementation detail*, it doesn't change the semantics of the request.